# geometry/quantizationParameters vs. cacheHint/resultOffset/resultRecordCount

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Very simple code, something like this:

```
const featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    url: "https://domain.org/arcgis/rest/services/Layer1/FeatureServer/0",
});
map.add(featureLayer);
```

This generates me automatically requets with payload like this:

[image: cacheHint]

The result is not satisfying.

When I load the same featurelayer within the new Map Viewer Beta it makes requests with a payload like this, so with a geometry parameter:

[image: querystring]

And the performance is much better!

If I change with my first sample only from Layer1 to Layer2 it takes the same payload as within the Map Viewer Beta, with the geometry parameter.

So somehow it's not depending to the code and also not to the published layer?! What it depends on and is it possible to force the request with the geometry/quantzationParameters instead of cacheHint/resultOffset somehow?

Used versions:
ArcGis Enterprise 10.8.1, Javascript API 4.22 / 4.23 (issue with both versions)

Comment: Which version of the JSAPI and which version of MapViewer (Online/Enterprise) are you using?

Comment: @BjornSvensson Thx for the hint. I've updated it in the post